# How to run PhantomJS driver from a servlet in a dynamic web project?

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, servlets

I am calling a Junit Test Case from a servlet.

I have added all the required JAR files. I have set the correct path for exe. When I am changing the driver to Firefox, it works fine. I want the test suites to be run on a headless browser. I am using Tomcat 8 server to run the web app.

```
Class ExTestCase {
    public static void someRandomMethod(){
        Capabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
        ((DesiredCapabilities) caps).setJavascriptEnabled(true);                
        ((DesiredCapabilities) caps).setCapability("takesScreenshot", true);  
        ((DesiredCapabilities) caps).setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY,"path to exe file");
        WebDriver gDriver = new PhantomJSDriver(caps);

        // WebDriver gDriver = new FirefoxDriver(); //THIS WORKS FINE, doesn't generate any error.  

        // Navigate to google
    }
}

Class ExServlet {
    void doGet method(){
        ExTestCase.someRandomMethod();
    }
}
```

Exception

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception    
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) root cause - 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
org/openqa/selenium/browserlaunchers/Proxies 
org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.Phant‌​omJSDriverService.createDefaultService(PhantomJSDriverService.java:178) 
org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriver.<init>(PhantomJSDriver.java:99)
```

Comment: What is your error message?

Comment: @feargal Not sure, how this error message is going to help you. But here it is - `exception - javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/browserlaunchers/Proxies org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverService.createDefaultService(PhantomJSDriverService.java:178) org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriver.<init>(PhantomJSDriver.java:99)`

Comment: can you add all relevant source code please?